# Jquery - Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: jquery, plugins, undefined

Here is my plugin:

```
    (function($){

    $.fn.stats_calc = function(options){

        var param = {
            param1:1000,
            param2:800,
            param3:0
        };

        this.each(function(){

            console.log("test : " + $(this).data('attribute').power);

        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

When I refresh my page, here is what I have in the console :

```
   test : 1
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'power' of undefined - stats_calc.js:18
```

So the variable is read (this is the "1") but the console tells me that the same variable isn't defined !

EDIT :

My element on which I apply the plugin has the following data named "attribute":

```
data-attribute = {
                                power:1,
                                sub:4,
                                xen:0,
                            };
```

If you have any idea it would help me a lot ! Thanks.

Comment: Show how the data is being set . Also are you trying to get a property that hasn't been defined yet? A demo that replicates problem would be helpful

Comment: With `each`, you are running a loop. Your console is telling you that the first iteration is fine and the second is not.

Comment: That's not a valid HTML attribute value. neither is a valid JS property

Comment: What I don't understand is that outside of my plugin I have no error when I display in console the same variable